# What is the difference between the "inheritance" tag and the "genetics" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

Is [genetics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genetics) a kind of meta-tag for [inheritance](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inheritance)?

If a question is about how genes are passed to child, could I add both tags? If not, should [inheritance](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inheritance) be preferred each time it applies?

But when does it apply?
Is inheritance specific to the next generation?

To sum up: What is the usage for those 2 tags.

Comment: IMO [tag:inheritance] should not have existed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have merged questions tagged with [inheritance](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inheritance) with [genetics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genetics).

Also, I have synonymized [inheritance](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inheritance) with [genetics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genetics) (master tag).

Answer (score 0):

Genetics is a vast area. Inheritance is only one phenomenon studied in genetics. So IMO that is more specific term.

Comment: But is there a case where genetics is not about inheritance?

Comment: Then,  for 1. more nonspecific purpose, genetics tag could be used. 2. For more specific purpose, such as variation (no tags yet, recombination and mutation are 2 close tag), gene-expression, etc. appropriate tage may be used.

Comment: Seems a bit too complicated and specific to me. The simpler the better IMO.